# how to get the property value of IEnumerable and assign it to variable in C#?

Tags: c#, list, ienumerable

I'm using List for my data collection but decided to try IEnumerable. I'm trying to assign the value of the SHIFT property of my Attendance Class to another Datagidviwcell.

This one works for me when I'm using List;

```
dgview.Rows[rowindex].Cell[cellindex].value = mylist.Find(x => x.Date == datevalue).SHIFT;
```

how do I do this when I'm using IEnumerable instead of List;

Comment: @zaggler you statement is equal to `mylist.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Date == datevalue)?.SHIFT` - the only differnce is that yours is slower in all cases except the match is the last entry or there is no match

Answer (score 1):

Already solve it. Replace Find with First...

```
dgview.Rows[rowindex].Cell[cellindex].value = mylist.First(x => x.Date == datevalue).SHIFT;
```

Comment: Note: to be comparable with `Find` in the case when there is no match, you should use `FirstOrDefault`, not `First`

Comment: If you only expect exactly one match, you might want to use Single() instead of First() as it will throw an exception if there is not exactly one.